# How do I let TS compiler know a function exist in an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typing

How do I let TS compiler know a method is in an object?

I have a function, purpose of that is check a function is in an object, my expecting is if hasFunction returns true, that means function exist in object that I'm checking, and typescript compiler stop giving me error:

```
function hasFunction(obj: any, func: string) {
    if (func in obj && (typeof obj[func] === "function"))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I tried to use it, but received an error:

```
function callMyFunc(obj: object) {
    if (hasFunction(obj, "myFunc")) {
        obj.myFunc();
    }
}
// error: Property 'myFunc' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

I tried something like that, but 'in' is not a valid syntax:

```
function hasFunction(obj: any, func: string): func in obj
```

so what can I do to let compiler know that function exist on object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function needs to be generic over `func`. You can store its literal type in a generic type `K`. Now we only need a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), so that the caller knows that `obj` has a key `K` which holds a function.

For the function type, you have to choose the right type for your needs. I went with the *"unsafe"* `any` approach. In the type guard, you can't really check parameter and return types of the function because they don't exist at runtime. So you might as well just type them as `unknown`.

```
function hasFunction<K extends string>(obj: any, func: K): obj is { 
  [Key in K]: (...args: any) => any 
} {
    return func in obj && (typeof obj[func] === "function")
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABACwIYGcBi5rzAHgGlEBTADyhLABN1F0oAnGMAcwD4AKOAIwCsAXIlRgAngBpEoSEMIBKIbz6IYdAN6IA2oRKiVSQgF0hnAHTnUjVuiEjRcxAF52wsYgC+iNQFgAUIgDGEigQRiRpCH1EJUQAMljETihRAAcSOGBo-k0IwydHR0QAIgjYBCK5P3c-P1K8RAhUABsmgFlRbEhufkV+EmgHH38AlUzONCwcMrBuvkkigFsOnArBvxGNrL5TJc6ITjkAbnWR6t93IA)